# How to select maximum 7 checkboxes in a 6x3 checkbox grid with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, max, rows

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to select a maximum of 7 (or x) checkboxes in a 6x3 checkbox grid - where at least one checkbox is required to be checked in each row. Each row is a new html checkbox tag with a unique id.

Example:

```
Row1:   [ ] - [x] - [ ]

Row2:   [x] - [ ] - [ ]

Row3:   [ ] - [x] - [ ]

Row4:   [ ] - [ ] - [x]

Row5:   [ ] - [ ] - [x]

Row6:   [x] - [ ] - [ ]
```

The example above show the six rows where at least one checkbox is required to be checked. The 7th checkbox the user can then freely check wherever he wants.  In other words:  Each row can max. get checked 2 times and at least one checkbox needs to be checked in each row.

The ultimate solution would be a flexible one where its fairly easy to edit the code, so a 8th or 9th checkbox can be checked as well - and maybe even make it possible to check all three boxes in one row.

Thanks in advance...its kind of a tricky one, this one :-)

Comment: You should show what you've tried and describe how it fails to do what you want.

Comment: This isn't the free software desk. Please show what you've done and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: I have tried fiddling with this:  http://jsfiddle.net/frhpP/  - but this limits every row to x amount of checkboxes checked. What i cant figure out is how to "reset" the other row to a 1 limit checkbox check, when one row has reached 2 checkbox checks...if you know what i mean?

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense and is ambiguous. You say there can be a maximum of seven checkboxes checked, and at least one per row. What happens if I check all the boxes in row 1, row 2, and one from row 3?

Comment: Let me try to explain.  Its to be used for predicting sportsgame outcomes. So lets say the Kings meets the Penguins. First checkbox is a Kings win, second checkbox is a tie, third checkbox is a Penguins win.  There are 6 matches so each match is required to have an outcome. However...in one (or more) matches, the user can place 2 outcomes as an advantage. Say he checks the first and second checkbox for the Kings vs Penguins match, thus enhancing his chances to predict the outcome.  Now..if he uses that advantage, he cant use that in the other 5 matches.  Hope that makes sense? :)

Comment: So the rule is really that you can only check two boxes in one row? (and then one in each other row)

Comment: Exactly what i mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes that your checkboxes are laid out using an HTML table.  I know that a lot of people are anti-table, so if you're using a table-less layout, hopefully you can adapt this to your particular case.

Rules followed:

- At least one box per row must be checked
- Only one row may have two boxes checked
- No row should have two winners checked (not enforced in the update further below)

Javascript:

```
$(function()
  {
      $('button').click(function()
          {
              var hedgeUsed = false;
              var validPicks = false;

              $('tr').each(function(){
                  if($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length == 0)
                  {
                      alert('A selection must be made for each match');
                      validPicks = false;
                      return false;
                  }
                  else if($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length >= 2)
                  {
                      if($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length == 3 || ($(this).find(':checkbox').first().is(':checked') && $(this).find(':checkbox').last().is(':checked')))
                      {
                          alert('You may only select one winner per match');
                          validPicks = false;
                          return false;
                      }

                      if(hedgeUsed)
                      {
                          alert('You may only hedge one bet');
                          validPicks = false;
                          return false;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          hedgeUsed = true;
                      }
                  }

                  validPicks = true;
              });

              if(validPicks)
              {
                  alert('submit the picks now');
                  // submit the picks
              }
          }
      );
  }
);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/frhpP/95/)

**Updated Javascript** (based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640040/how-to-select-maximum-7-checkboxes-in-a-6x3-checkbox-grid-with-jquery/24640772?noredirect=1#comment38225053_24640772))

```
$(function()
  {
      $(':checkbox').click(function(){
          $thisParentParentChildren = $(this).parent().parent().children();

          if($(this).is(':checked'))
          {
              var hedgeUsed = false;

              $('tr').each(function(){
                  if($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length == 2)
                  {
                      hedgeUsed = true;
                      return false;
                  }
              });

              if(hedgeUsed)
              {
                  $('tr').each(function(){
                      if($(this).children().children(':checked').length > 0)
                      {
                          $(this).children().children().not(':checked').each(function(){
                             $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                          });
                      }
                  });
              }
              else if(
                  $thisParentParentChildren
                      .children(':checked').not($(this)).length > 0
              )
              {
                  $thisParentParentChildren
                      .children().not(':checked').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              }
          }
          else
          {
              $thisParentParentChildren.children(':checkbox').each(function(){
                  $(this).attr('disabled', ''); 
              });

              if(
                  $thisParentParentChildren
                      .children(':checked').not($(this)).length > 0
              )
              {
                  $(':checkbox').each(function(){
                     $(this).attr('disabled', ''); 
                  });
              }
          }
      });

      $('button').click(function()
          {
              var validPicks = false;

              $('tr').each(function(){
                  if($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length == 0)
                  {
                      alert('A selection must be made for each match');
                      validPicks = false;
                      return false;
                  }

                  validPicks = true;
              });

              if(validPicks)
              {
                  alert('submit the picks now');
                  // submit the picks
              }
          }
      );
  }
);
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/frhpP/97/)**

I didn't spend a ton of time on this, so the DOM traversals may or may not be the most efficient, but they work.

Comment: This is 98% of the perfect answer and solution! :)   The third and last rule isnt required, as a user CAN choose checkbox 1 and 3 (home winner and away winner) one time only.  Is it possible to disable the remaining checkboxes in each row when necessary? Other than that...it's peeerfect and i cant thank you enough for your help :)

Comment: I guess I was thinking that picking two winners would be the same as picking a tie, but I can see that in the sense of betting it wouldn't be. I'll make the requested change later (have some "real" work to do right now).

Comment: Awesome! One tiiiny thing tho (sorry)...if you have selected 2 checkboxes in a row..and fills out the rest of the rows but then decides to change your mind about one of the one-checkbox-rows...the disabled row-boxes stays disabled if you uncheck the checked box.  Example: row 1 has two boxes checked. Row 2-7 have one checkbox checked. I then decide to uncheck the box in row 4...but then the two non-checked disabled boxes remains disabled so i cant choose one of those instead.  Hope im making sense :)

Comment: @petrucci Okay, I'ved edited the update to account for that, plus added a minor optimization.

Comment: It works exactly like i wanted it too now. Thank you very much for your help, Patrick! :-)   - In case i decide for more flexibility (say for example two rows can have 2 checked boxes...is this easy to fix? I tried fiddling with a new counter variable with no luck so far)

Comment: @petrucci That shouldn't be a hard change. Just have `hedgeUsed` be an integer counter instead of a boolean (and maybe change the name to `hedgeCount` or `hedgesUsed` or something). Initialize it to `0`. Then, instead of setting `hedgeUsed = true;` you set `hedgeCount++;` and instead of checking `if(hedgeUsed)` you check `if(hedgeCount == hedgeLimit)` (where `hedgeLimit` obviously equals the max number of rows where you allow two selections). That's all I'm going to give you as part of this answer though :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.subscriber :checkbox').click(function(e){ //When a checkbox is clicked...
    if($(".subscriber :checkbox:checked").length > 7){ //...check if the user is attempting to check the eighth checkbox...
        e.preventDefault(); //...and stop it from being checked if needed.
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/frhpP/93/

Comment: Some of explanation of your code always goes a long way.

Comment: This doesn't require at least one checkbox in each row, which the OP apparently requires.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(e){
    if($(":checkbox:checked").length >= 7){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't require at least one checkbox in each row, which the OP apparently requires.